# How to change button text in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, button, jquery-autocomplete

I have this working code so far:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r4emt/12/

Right now before you enter the JQuery UI autocomplete, the button reads "Hello".  You can type "item" in the JQuery UI autocomplete and you'll notice the button now says "World".  Click on the "world" button to put item in the list.  If you type item again you can select one and click the replace button on an item already in the list.  However once you do this, The button still says "world" but it should say "hello" because there is nothing in the input field.  If you click in the input field and then hit delete or back arrow it changes back to "hello" but there isn't anything there to delete or go to the left of.  I think it has to do with this part of the code:

```
$('#inputWrapper').on('keyup', '#tags', function() {
    if($(this).val() == '') {
        $('button.addButton').text('Hello');
    } else {
        $('button.addButton').text('World');
    }
});
```

Specifically the 'keyup' part.  So my question is how can I fix this so that whenever the input box is empty the button always reads "hello" and when there is input in the field, the button reads "world"?  Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you use the `textchanged` event instead of relying purely on keyup as it would work even if someone pastes or drag-drops text into your input: http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-text-change-custom-event

Comment: Wow thanks for the suggestion! Looks like this is exactly what I need.  How exactly do I install that plugin? And does it matter where I include the <script> line?  Thanks

Comment: Are you reinventing the HTML5 placeholder attribute?

Comment: @epascarello I'm sorry, I don't really understand what you mean.  Can you please explain?  Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/r4emt/36/) is the working fiddle. Changes made are:

```
$('#tags').keyup( function() {
    if($(this).val() == '') {
        $('button.addButton').text('Hello');
    } else {
        $('button.addButton').text('World');        
    }
});
```

and at the end of your button click:

```
$('#tags').val('');
$('#tags').keyup();
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, but this didn't fix the problem. If you replace, the button still says "world".

Comment: I've commented below, but I'll add it here just encase: Using .text() on a button element causes memory leaks in javaScript. Use .html() instead.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is a long dead thread, but I needed to add this, because I've just spent 2 days tracking down a memory leak (Caused by me using code from this page).

**IMPORTANT: Do not use jQuerys text() on button elements!**

The function creates something in the DOM that cannot be removed by empty(). If you then call the function multiple times over a long period a large amount of rubbish will be plopped in your DOM, causing stuff to break.

See [jQuery API documentation.](https://api.jquery.com/text/)

(Can't find exactly where its mentioned in the documentation, but its in there somewhere, I've got to run for my train now)...

Comment: Doesn't sound very trustworthy, to be honest. There's a potential leak described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16405533/33080), but a statement like "do not use text()" with no explanation is too un-specific.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just set the text back to Hello after they click it? Add this to the bottom of your button click function:

```
$(this).text('Hello');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r4emt/13/

Comment: I appreciate the help, but this didn't fix the problem. If you replace, the button still says "world".

Comment: I'm not seeing your sortable list in the fiddle. All I see is a textbox and a button.

Answer (score 1):

[jsFiddle Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/r4emt/17/)

```
    $('#inputWrapper').on('keyup', '#tags', function() {
        if($(this).val() == "") {
            $('button.addButton').html('Hello1');
        } else {
            $('button.addButton').html('World');
        }
    });
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, but this didn't fix the problem.  If you replace, the button still says "world".

Answer (score 0):

Put the condition like this

`if($.trim($(this).val()) == '')`

to remove unwanted spaces. Also, you should change the button text to "Hello" in the handler of the click event

Add this at the end of the click function:
`$(this).text('Hello');`

Here's the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/r4emt/34/

Comment: I appreciate the help, but this didn't fix the problem. If you replace, the button still says "world".

Comment: Do you have a function that runs when the button is clicked?

Comment: Yeah, the last function in the js file.

Comment: I edited my answer. It's not the last function, it's this function $(".addButton").click(function(e) {}); 

It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

This function only works the first time because after it is executed the event listener is always going to be evaluated after keyup resulting the input box to always have a value. You will notice that once you click the button if you type something and erase it pressing backspace it will change back to Hello.

To achieve your desired results, when you click submit on the button since you are clearing
out the input box, you can also change the text there as well.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/r4emt/37/

I just added:

```
//refreshes button name
$(this).text('Hello');
```

to the end of the button click function.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'text' function

```
       $("#inputWrapper").click(function () {
        $(this).text(function(i, v){
           return v === 'Hello' ? 'World' : 'Hello'
        })
```